# excel macro to import a csv file entered by user which is in shared drive and combine all the rows to one

Tags: excel, vba

I need an Excel macro code that opens the user specified .csv file that exists in a shared drive and combines all the text into an array variable. This code is just a part of my case function.
**Eg,**
My csv file looks like this(It just has one column only)

- line 1:apple|orange|grapes
- line 2:potato|onion

Required output

```
searchTerms="apple|orange|grapes|potato|onion,..."
```

This was my attempt in writing the code:

```
Case Is = 4
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)

If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub
lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
For i = 1 To lrow
    counter = counter + 1
    If counter = lrow Then Exit Sub

    Cells(i, 1).Value
    searchTerms = Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) & "|" & " " & Cells(i + 1, 1).Value

    Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    i = i - 1
Next i
```

Using Application.Workbooks.Open (csvFileName) opened the required file as Jane suggested but still not able to figure out why its showing error  at Cells(i,1).Value. So basically not able to combine all the data (in csv)  into searchTerms still.

Comment: What's your question though? Seems to be "Can someone write some code for me?"  That's not how it works here.

Comment: @Tim I have attempted to write the code. But it did not work at my first step. So thought the approach was wrong and expected new ideas

Comment: Always helps to add any code you might have, even if it's not working.  People here (including me) can be quick to close questions which have no code...

Comment: @Tim I am having error with Cells(i,1). value. Is there a way may be better to combine all the rows in one string(I just have one column) separated by "|" and assigned to searchTerms

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN topic for GetOpenFilename (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195744(v=office.11).aspx) describes what this function does:
"Displays the standard Open dialog box and gets a file name from the user without actually opening any files."

This means that after calling GetOpenFileName, your code will need to actually open the file:

```
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)
If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub

Application.Workbooks.Open (csvFileName)
```

UPDATE:

The line Cells(i, 1).Value is giving an error because there isn't a valid statement or instruction for VBA to handle. You can use this statement to retrieve the value from a cell:

```
x = Cells(i, 1).Value
```

or to set the value in a cell:

```
Cells(i, 1).Value =x
```

but you're not doing either of those things. This line isn't doing anything useful and can be removed.

There are several other problems with the code. The following line finds out how many rows are in the sheet, then checks the row number of that row (eg if there are 3 rows, it asks for the row number of row 3):

```
lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
```

You can just use:

```
lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

When you go through the loop, you take the value from the first cell, and add the pipe and the value from the current cell:

```
searchTerms = Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) & "|" & " " & Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
```

However, this value is then thrown away when you get to the next cell, and you combine the value from the first cell with the pipe and the latest cell. This will work if there are only 2 rows, but for any more, you'll only end up with the values from the first and last cell. You could either store the updated searchTerms value in the first cell at each step in the loop, or you can just combine the values correctly as you go along.

Deleting the rows as you go along is probably causing the code to be more convoluted than it needs to be (eg needing to change the value of i within the loop and having a separate variable which exits the loop. I'd suggest avoiding that and just loop through the cells to create the searchTerms value. If you really need to delete the values, I'd do so afterwards. Here's how I've updated the code:

```
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)
If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub

Application.Workbooks.Open (csvFileName)

lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To lrow
    If i = 1 Then
        searchTerms = Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Else
        searchTerms = searchTerms & "|" & Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print searchTerms
```

One additional point is that you've added a space after the pipe symbol when joining the strings. I've left that in, but it's not in your sample text, so you may need to remove it.

Comment: :I am not sure how to combine using find and replace, All I want to do is combine all the rows -how many ever is present in the csv file into one string searchTerms

Comment: @Jane- I think using   :     searchTerms = searchTerms & "|" & " " & Trim(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value) would miss second row so It  works with just Trim(Cells(i,1).Value)

Comment: With the small correction in the code (changing Trim(Cells(i,1).Value) works good. Thanks for the help!!!